Efficiency of Redis compared to relational DBs in Python
Edit: pipelining in redis script is used to execute commands in batches, it doesnt connect to the remote server for each operation
I use connectionpool for Redis to maximize the network delays
Edit2: I wouldnt use Redis Search because it concludes to using index and part of my tests is to see the times without indexing.
My data contains of 6mln rows with such columns:
'primary_key', 'timestamp', 'temperature_value','sensor_id', 'sensor_status'
e.g.
1, 2023-01-01 00:00:00.0, 20.28, 1, GOOD
The data was written to Redis as hash values.
I am experimenting with Redis, MySQL, PostgreSQL and InfluxDB with use of their python libraries.
For the dbs used, we want a filtered data - from all rows only those where sensor_id in (1,2,8) (in csv file sensor_id takes values from 1-10.).
For those sensor_ids we query select amounts: 10k, 20k, 40k, 80k, 160k, 320k overall.
For each amount we query it 10 times to get a time average for used database and query amount which results in 6 average times for 4 databases each. Each query has a different offset set such so it doesn't exceed the data size. (it was done in order to have different results from each query)
My scripts (written in Python) execute queries with such fragments to measure the time for each database:
Redis:
 start_time = time.time()
    pipeline = connection.pipeline()
    for key in filtered_keys:
        pipeline.hgetall(key)
    values = pipeline.execute()
    end_time = time.time()

MySQL:
start_time = time.time()
    # SELECT query
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE sensor_id IN ({sensor_ids_str}) LIMIT {Offset}, {Amount};"
    cursor.execute(query)
    # Execute the query and fetch the results
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    # Record the end time
    end_time = time.time()

PostgreSQL:
start_time = time.time()
        select_query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE sensor_id IN ({sensor_ids_str}) OFFSET {random_offset} LIMIT {rows_amount};"
        cursor.execute(select_query)
        result = cursor.fetchall() 
        end_time = time.time()

InfluxDB:
sensor_ids = [1, 2, 8]
sensor_ids_str = ' OR '.join([f"sensor_id='{sensor_id}'" for sensor_id in sensor_ids])
    time1 = time.time()
    # Perform the SELECT query
    result = client.query(f'SELECT * FROM {measurement_name} WHERE ({sensor_ids_str}) LIMIT {num_points} OFFSET {random_offset};')
    time2 = time.time()

The part that concerns me is that results of these queries show that Redis takes the longest time to finish such operation, although I believe it should have a bigger efficiency as an in-memory database. I am currently reading about the possible reasons for the results I got. I have to be missing something, so if you know something about this case, please share your thoughts. :)
The results I got:
graph of the results
On the graph we have 4 databases with query sizes and divided into query times with database disturbance and without disturbance (the disturbance means simultaneous write operations). It is another thing I tested but the main point would be answering why Redis has the biggest retrieval time. Thanks.
Redis for 320k rows retrieval took under 12 seconds, while Postgres needed under 4s.
Before I included filtering by sensor_id, Redis was having almost the best performance results. From the moment I included the filtering and changed a script due to this, Redis became the slowest. I think it may not handle well the filtering, but it shouldn't be a problem because I measure only the pipeline which is retrieving a list of filtered keys.
results without interruptions before including filtering
I don't have currently the old code, but it wasn't using pipelining for Redis, yet the results were so better.

A simple key lookup in Redis should be roughly 100 times faster than a select query in SQL.

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you are making a query to Redis for every filtered key you have, but you are just making one query to Postgres with all the keys at once. Query for query Redis is definitely faster than Postgres, but if you constantly going back and forth for the results between your code and Redis that will definitely slow things way down. Even on a local machine that can make a difference, but imagine your Redis/Potsgres db is on a different server somewhere, that will add up quickly.
You are also comparing the speed of one query vs the speed of many queries

I will definitely try to make a hgetall() for all Keys at once, but probably will have to do this in batches anyway. Thanks! And the script is connecting to a seperate virtual machine, which I didnt mention in the post.

Might be worth looking at Redis' search and query capability for this. It's part of Redis Stack and would let you do a single query to get a better comparison.

This (Redis Search) would be used to run normal queries? I will definitely try, got some video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=infTV4ifNZY

InfluxDB is faster than Redis here because it's built for time data. It automatically organizes timestamps and sensor IDs, making searches quick. InfluxDB's structure fits your data better than Redis's simpler setup. Its query system is made for time-based questions, which is exactly what you're doing.
